# C++ default constructor using inheritance from abstract class

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, virtual-functions, default-constructor

**Hi I'm new to C++ and having trouble with the following code:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Shape
{
public:
    virtual void area() = 0;
    virtual void perimeter() = 0;
    virtual void volume() = 0;
};


class Circle : public Shape
{
protected:
    int r;


public:
    Circle()
    {
        r = 0;
    }


    Circle(int num)
    {
        r = num;
    }


    void area()
    {
        double area = (r * r) * (3.14);
        cout << "The area of the circle = " << area << endl;
    }


    void perimeter()
    {
        double perimeter = 2 * (3.14) * r;
        cout << "The circumference of the circle = " << perimeter << endl;

    }


    void volume()
    {
        cout << "You are tapping into another dimension. AHHH Error!" << endl;
    }

};




class Sphere : public Circle
{

protected:
    int r;

public:
    Sphere() :Circle()
    {
        r = 0;
    }

    Sphere(int num) : Circle(num)
    {
        r = num;
    }

    void area()
    {
        double area = 4 * (3.14) * (r * r);
        cout << "The surface area of the sphere = " << area << endl;
    }

    void perimeter()
    {
        double perimeter = 2 * (3.14) * r;
        cout << "The circumference of the sphere = " << perimeter << endl;
    }

    void volume()
    {
        double volume = ((4 / 3) * (3.14) * (r * r * r));
        cout << "The volume of the sphere = " << volume << endl;
    }

};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Shape *ptr;

    Circle c1(5);
    Circle c2();

    Sphere sp1(6);
    Sphere sp2();

    ptr = &c1;
    ptr->perimeter();
    ptr->area();
    ptr->volume();

    ptr = &c2;
    ptr->perimeter();
    ptr->area();
    ptr->volume();

    ptr = &sp1;
    ptr->perimeter();
    ptr->area();
    ptr->volume();

    ptr = &sp2;
    ptr->perimeter();
    ptr->area();
    ptr->volume();

    return 0;
}
```

**The console tells me this:**

> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'Circle (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'Shape *'
>   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'Sphere (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'Shape *'

---

**NOTE:**
I get these ERRORS on the lines containing: "**ptr = &c2;**" and "**ptr = &sp2;**"

This is only for the instances that use a constructor with no parameters.
The constructors with parameters work for some reason??
Any help would be nice. Thanks!!!

Comment: *Where* do you get these errors? On which lines?

Comment: I get them on the lines containing: "ptr = &c2;" and "ptr = &sp2;"

Comment: Just a tip for next time: please **reduce** the code you post here to get just a MWE (minimal working example). This will expand the chances that you get a response. You could have done this here easily. Nobody wants to parse through dozens of unrelated lines of code.

Comment: The vast majority of this code example was not necessary to demonstrate the program. Create a [testcase](http://sscce.org) next time: in doing so, you'll likely find the problem yourself, even. This is called _debugging_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of building an object using a no-arguments constructor is

```
 Circle c2;
```

**Not**

```
 Circle c2();
```

This latter line is a function declaration.

Comment: Fixed!!! Wowwww... Thank you! I really derped on that one.. I really appreciate the help (mam||sir)!

Answer (score 0):

```
Circle c2();
```

That does not declare a `Circle`; it declares a function.

**Just write `Circle c2;`.**

Same for your `Sphere` declaration underneath.

Your hint is that the error message said `'Circle (__cdecl *)(void)'`, which is a function pointer type.

Comment: Fixed!!! Wowwww... Thank you! I really derped on that one.. I really appreciate the help (mam||sir)!